Remove tag from xml in python
I want to remove root element from an etree obtained with  etree.fromstring()
I had to have a valid xml that's why I had to include  but I don't need in my final payload
For instance
<data> <element_1>element-1</element_1> <element_2>element-2</element_2> </data>
to be
<element_1>element-1</element_1> <element_2>element-2</element_2> 
I tried to use getchildren  
but  return a list and I have :
TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got list)
e = etree.fromstring(content)
children = e.getchildren()


from the documenation for ElementTree
https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml
We see that you parse the root node with fromstring, then we access its children by iterating over that Element.
You say you want instances of Element, for the immediate children of the root, which is covered in that documentation as:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<data> <element_1>element-1</element_1> <element_2>element-2</element_2> </data>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
for child in root:
    print(type(child), child.tag, child.text)

The output of that print is to prove that it is an Element as requested, and that it contains the immediate children of the root. From there, you can do what you need with those elements
But the question you posted gives an expected output in string format, which would be
root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
output = ''.join((ET.tostring(child).decode() for child in root))
print(output)


<element_1>element-1</element_1> <element_2>element-2</element_2>

Your code seems to be using getchildren, which was deprecated in 3.2 and "will be removed in 3.9" (although I'm running 3.10 and it seems to be calling something, but I'm not sure how looking at the cpython source code). I'd suggest ignoring that and just using the documented interface.

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def remove_root(xml_str):
    root = ET.fromstr(xml_str)
    return root[1:]  

xml_str = '<data> <element_1>element-1</element_1> <element_2>element-2</element_2> </data>'

remaining_ele = remove_root(xml_str)
print(ET.tostr(remaining_ele).decode())

It creates a list of elements and slice it to remove the first element.
